# Datatype not shown for columns in SQLite when created with python script

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am creating an SQL database and a table in it using python.
I then open it in SQLite, to see the structure of the table.
I can see the names of the columns but the Datatype is not shown even though I set it in the code.
This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db') 
c = conn.cursor() 


# Create table - TICKERS
c.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE1
            (column1 text, 
             column2 test, 
             column3 float, 
             column4 text) """)

# add data to table
ticker_list_df.to_sql('TABLE1', conn, if_exists='append', index = False) 
                
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Drop the table and run the code again to verify.

Comment: You are right, it works now.